# python function Returns a dictionary containing values along with a corresponding list of keys that had that value from the original dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary and im creating a function that takes the each value that is the same and make a new dictionary with the keys of value. i have some doc test for some example. i believe this can be done in one line using list comprehension.

```
>>> rating = {"bob": "excellent", "barnum": "passing", "beatrice": "satisfactory", "bernice": "passing", "ben": "no pass", "belle": "excellent", "bill": "passing", "bernie": "passing", "baxter": "excellent"}
>>> new_dict(rating) # new_dict is the function
>>> {'excellent': ['bob', 'belle', 'baxter'], 'passing': ['barnum', 'bernice', 'bill', 'bernie'], 'satisfactory': ['beatrice'], 'no pass': ['ben']}
```

Comment: You should show us your attempts so we can help you debug.  StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and sorting to do a one-liner:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> {k:[x[0] for x in g] for k,g in groupby(sorted(rating.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]),lambda x:x[1])}
{'passing': ['bernice', 'barnum', 'bernie', 'bill'], 'no pass': ['ben'], 'excellent': ['belle', 'baxter', 'bob'], 'satisfactory': ['beatrice']}
>>>
```

but this is needlessly inefficient, it requires a sorting operation that materializes an auxilliary list, and it is overcomplicated. Don't strive to write one-liners. Write clean readable code that uses python data-structures efficiently. Just use a `collections.defaultdict` for this, that is the canonical way to group things:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> grouper = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in rating.items():
...     grouper[v].append(k)
...
>>> grouper
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'passing': ['bernice', 'barnum', 'bernie', 'bill'], 'excellent': ['belle', 'baxter', 'bob'], 'satisfactory': ['beatrice'], 'no pass': ['ben']})
>>>
```

Comment: @Errick-MichaelSantos there's nothing wrong with doing it for fun, though. Check out https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I see no good way to write this as a comprehension. Consider a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html) module.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> result = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in rating.items():
...:    result[v].append(k)
...:    
>>> result
>>> 
defaultdict(list,
            {'excellent': ['bob', 'baxter', 'belle'],
             'no pass': ['ben'],
             'passing': ['barnum', 'bernice', 'bill', 'bernie'],
             'satisfactory': ['beatrice']})
```

This has time complexity O(n), any comprehension I tried out, such as

```
>>> {v:[k for k, v_ in rating.items() if v_ == v] for v in rating.values()}
>>> 
{'excellent': ['bob', 'baxter', 'belle'],
 'no pass': ['ben'],
 'passing': ['barnum', 'bernice', 'bill', 'bernie'],
 'satisfactory': ['beatrice']}
```

is much worse at O(n**2).

Comment: I see, i guess it was not possible for a one liner. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Used list comprehension to shorten the answer as much as I could. I'm sure there's a way to reduce the function to a single line.

```
def new_dict(rating):
    my_dict = dict([(i,[]) for i in set([value for key,value in rating.items()])])
    [my_dict[value].append(key) for key,value in rating.items()]
    return my_dict

rating = {"bob": "excellent", "barnum": "passing", "beatrice": "satisfactory", "bernice": "passing", "ben": "no pass", "belle": "excellent", "bill": "passing", "bernie": "passing", "baxter": "excellent"}
print(new_dict(rating)) # new_dict is the function
```

This prints an output of:

```
{'excellent': ['bob', 'belle', 'baxter'], 'passing': ['barnum', 'bernice', 'bill', 'bernie'], 'satisfactory': ['beatrice'], 'no pass': ['ben']}
```

Comment: Hi, this is actually not very pythonic to use list comprehensions to apply a function (and not storing the result): it is better to replace `[my_dict[value].append(key) for key,value in rating.items()]` by a `for` loop.